# Django how to write DRY views

Tags: django, django-views

I have many views that call the same functions every time and I wonder before I go ahead with this approach if anyway I can make it more DRY.

For example I have many pages on a site that have on the left side menu a list of the same articles and photos. So on each of my views I do the following:

```
context_dict = {'articles': get_articles(blogger.id), 'photos': get_photos(blogger.id)}

return render_to_response('...', context_dict, context)
```

It must exist a way that I don't have to repeat myself every time since they are required on 90% of the pages.

Comment: Take a look at "context processors" and "middleware"

Comment: Problem with those options is that I need to pass the blogger_id and it is not available in the request.

Comment: Where does it come from in that code you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like

```
def get_extra_context(blog_id):
    return {'articles': get_articles(blogger.id), 'photos': get_photos(blogger.id)}
```

A call to `get_extra_context` has to be made in every view of course.

Answer (score 2):

The issue of repeating view functionality is part of why many people like class-based views. You could implement a method that adds those variables to the base class, and then have other views inherit from that one, or provide a standardized "render" method. For example:

```
class BaseView(View):
    template = 'public/base_template.html'

    def get(self, *args, **options):
         return render_to_response(self.template, self.render_view())

    def render_view(self, *args, **options):
         context = {"photos": Photo.objects.all()}
         return context

class OtherView(BaseView):
    template = 'public/other_template.html'

    def render_view(self, *args, **options):
        context = super(OtherView, self).render_view(*args, **options)
        context['additional_context'] = True
        return context
```

...or something similar. Then, you don't have to worry about calling render with variables that are already included.

I can think of a few ways to accomplish this with function-based views, but I think class-based lends itself very well to DRY principles, so I thought I'd spread the gospel :)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Townley says, class based views are very helpful for keeping to DRY principles. I often use some simple mixins to share some logic between different views. Your class based views can then inherit from this mixin if they need this functionality. For example:

```
class BloggerMixin(object):
    articles_context_name = 'articles' 
    photos_context_name = 'photos'

    def get_blogger(self):
        """ I'm just assumming your blogger is the current user for simplicity.    
        (And I'm assuming they're logged in already)"""
        return self.request.user

    def get_articles(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(blogger=self.get_blogger())

    def get_photos(self):
        return Photo.objects.filter(blogger=self.get_blogger())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BloggerMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context[self.articles_context_name] = self.get_articles()
        context[self.photos_context_name] = self.get_photos()
        return context
```

This would allow you to inherit this extra functionality on class based views that need it:

```
class ExampleView(BloggerMixin, ListView):
    model = SomeOtherModel
```

Our very simple ExampleView class will now have a list of Article, Photo and SomeOtherModel in its context.